# Generating Coprime Integers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Is there a formula for generating a set of Coprime integers that every element of this set is coprime to the other elements in this set?

I want to create a collection of this formulas!

Comment: Set of prime numbers will satisfy your condition

Comment: @AtulMishra You're right, but i want a formula :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well take any number lets say $a_1$ then the next $a_2=a_1+1$ then the next $a_3=a_1a_2+1$ and so on.$a_n=a_1\cdots a_n+1$

Comment: Well, this is what Ribenboim used, right? :)

Comment: @GodeltheMaestro Maybe I based this on the Euclid's proof of infinite number of primes.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the sequence of Fermat numbers $a_n=2^{2^n}+1$, or the sequence of prime numbers, the latter don't have a nice formula.

Comment: Fermat thinks that this formula generates always primes, do you think that this delusion defines the despair of old mathematicians?

Comment: Fermat did not think so. He conjectured that there were infinitely many primes in the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

As shown above, a nice way is to add $1$. I think that this is rather a cool way of visualizing that $a \times b + 1$ will generate coprime integers (that is both $a$ and $b$ will not divide $a \times b + 1$).

Suppose $a = 3, b = 4$ then we have 4 rows of 3 dots so we can draw 3 vertical lines of 4 dots, or 4 horizontal lines of 3 dots

```
...
...
...
...
```

Now consider $a \times b + 1$

```
...
...
...
....
```