# closed formula for an increasing sequence of coprime positive terms that are as small as possible.

Tags: number-theory, soft-question, asymptotics, big-list

I would like to issue a challenge for the following problem:

Give a closed formula for term $a_n$ of an increasing sequence of positive integers $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$ such that $(a_i,a_j)=1$ for all $i,j$.

We say that one sequence $a_n$ is better than another $(b_n)$ if there exist $N$ such that $a_n\leq b_n$ for all $n\geq N$.

Right now the only example I have is $2^{2^n}+1$ from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2063302/generating-coprime-integers/2063309#2063309), but I look forward to contributing when I find something "better"

Comment: I think sequence of prime numbers is the best sequence.

Comment: yeah. that's not hard to show, but we don't have a closed formula for that one I think.

Comment: So the sequence must have a generalized formula.

Comment: yeah, you have to be able to give a closed formula for $a_n$ in terms of $n$.

Comment: I think this recurrence relation is better than the sequence you mentioned in the question.$$a_n=a_{n-1}^2-a_{n-1}+1$$ for $a_1=2$ and $n>1$. I am still trying to solve this recurrence.

Comment: There is a recursive formula (Ghandhi's formula) for the $n$th prime in terms of all the preceding primes.

Comment: I wasn't able to solve the recurrence relation and googled it and found the sequence formed is **A000058 OEIS** aka **Sylvester's sequence** and has the following closed form$$a_n=\lfloor E^{2^{n+1}}+\frac{1}{2}\rfloor$$ 
where $E=1.264084735305302$ approximately. And it is better than Fermat numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem turns out to not have a particularly well defined solution. One can do arbitrarily well at this game using any sequence that satisfies the assumptions. Consider the example of the the Fibonacci numbers, which are given by the well-known formula $F_n=\phi^n+(1-\phi)^n$. Given any sequence $a_n$ that only produces relatively prime numbers and has a closed form $\sigma(n)$ we can now construct a sequence that beats $a_n$ by looking at $F_{a_n}:=\phi^{\sigma(n)}+(1-\phi)^{\sigma(n)}$. Since $F_i \geq i$ holds for all positive $i$, $F_{a_n}\geq a_n$ holds for all $n$.

There might be a complexity theory-esque way to look at rates of growth of self-convolution though